# How can I pass interface method to function?

Tags: go, interface, functional-programming

I have an interface as follows:

```golang
type visitable interface {
    getName() string
    getLookupMessage() string
}
```

I want to make a function with the signature like `apply(visitable []visitable, function ???)` that accepts visitable's function (such as getName or getLookupMessage) as the second argument. Can I technically do that? And if yes, how?

Comment: You can simply pass the function only to `apply`. Do you really need to pass the `visitable` as well? If you pass a method of an object implementing `visitable`, that function will work on that instance of the object.

Comment: This seems very much like an X/Y Problem, can you give some details on what you're trying to do and how you arrived at this as the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in this specific case you can use [method expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions). This works because both interface methods have the same signature, i.e. the type of both `visitable.getName` and `visitable.getLookupMessage` is `func(visitable) string`:

```
package main

type visitable interface {
    getName() string
    getLookupMessage() string
}

func apply(vs []visitable, m func(visitable) string) {
    for _, v := range vs {
        m(v)
    }
}

func main() {
    apply(nil, visitable.getName)
    apply(nil, visitable.getLookupMessage)
}
```

However, given how trivial `apply` is, it's unclear why this would be useful, especially considering that this doesn't work for methods with different signatures.